# Set default return Value to false of Checkbox when untouched

Tags: angular, checkbox, default

I want to set the default value of my Angular Checkbox to false (if the Checkbox is untouched).
Is there a simple solution for this?

**My checkbox:**

```
<div class="notificationTitle margin-top-2">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div>
                            <label class="text-h4 margin-top-2"
                                    for="notifcation"></label>
                            <input
                            [formControlName]="InputField.Notification"
                            [name]="inputField.Notification"
                            id="notifcation"
                            type="checkbox"
                            >
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to solve this Issue is to add a If statement in the set(Notification) Method. That way the code checks if the Value is null, if thats true then it changes the Value to false:

```
    public setNotification(notificationInfo: FormNotificationInfo): void {
            if (notificationInfo.notification === null) {
                    notificationInfo.notification = false;
            }
            this.notificationInfo= notificationInfo;
    }
```